# assinging functions to function types that return interface values,

Tags: go

Im trying to define a couple of interface to refactor some code and I'm getting a problem where Go is not letting me assign functions to variables.
This is the set up

main.go

```
    type Gettable interface {
        Get() int64
    }

    type MyFunction func(int64) (Gettable, error)

    func main() {

        var f MyFunction
        f = sub.TestFn2
        a, _ := f(1)
        fmt.Println(a)
    }
```

main/sub

```
package sub

type MyStruct struct {
    Val int64
}

func (v MyStruct) Get() int64 {
    return v.Val
}

func TestFn2(a int64) (MyStruct, error) {
    return MyStruct{a}, nil
}
```

I'm trying to define a generic function type, and in the sub package create the concrete functions

and ideally i want to store the functions in a map and call them with something like

```
FnMap["fnName"]()
```

I'm not there yet,

im getting an error saying

```
/topics.go:27:4: cannot use sub.TestFn2 (type func(int64) (sub.MyStruct, error)) as type MyFunction in assignment
```

but `MyStruct` clearly implements the interface `Gettable`

Comment: There is no covariance in Go: function signatures must match exactly.

Comment: I suggest attaching the function to a `type`, it would be cleaner, and much more idiomatic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error occurs because of signature don't match.
You code shared is:

```
//shared code
//---------------------------------------------
type Gettable interface {
    Get() int64
}
type MyFunction func(int64) (Gettable, error)
```

So you need replace MyStruct by Gettable.

```
//main/sub
//---------------------------------------------
type MyStruct struct {
    Val int64
}

func (v MyStruct) Get() int64 {
    return v.Val
}

//this signature of TestFn2 is different of MyStruct
//-[TestFn2] func (a int64) (MyStruct, error)
//-[MyFunction] func(int64) (Gettable, error)
func TestFn2(a int64) (Gettable, error) {//<-- replace by Gettable here
    return MyStruct{a}, nil
}
```

Running your code:

```
//main.go
//---------------------------------------------

func main() {
        var f MyFunction
        f = TestFn2
        a, _ := f(1)
        fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Result is:

```
{1}
```

See in playground: https://play.golang.org/p/sRsXix8E_83

Answer (score 4):

As per the Go's [assignability rules](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) a function `f` is assignable to a variable `v` only if the variable's type `T` exactly matches the `f`'s signature.

The ability to assign a more specific type in some other languages called "covariance", and Go's type system does not have it.